# use cut inside awk to extract substring of a field

Tags: bash, awk, cut

1) I have a Source_File.csv which looks like this

```
A;B;/Path/xx/file1_name
C;D;/anotherPath/yyyyy/file2_name
```

2) I want to produce a Target_File.csv

```
A;B;/Path/xx/;/Path/xx/file1_name
C;D;/anotherPath/yyyyy/;/anotherPath/yyyyy/file2_name
```

The command

```
cat Source_File.csv | awk -F";" '{print $1";"$2";"echo $3 |
cut -d'/' -f1,2,3";"$3}' >> Target_File.csv;
```

gives this error

```
awk: {print $1";"$2";"echo $3 | cut -d/ -f1,2,3";"$3}
awk:                                       ^ syntax error
```

Thanks in advance for your Advices/Suggestions

Answer (score 3):

No need to use `cat`, `cut` etc. Just `awk` alone is enough:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {s=$NF; sub(/[^\/]+$/, "", s); print $1,$2,s,$NF}' Source_File.csv
A;B;/Path/xx/;/Path/xx/file1_name
C;D;/anotherPath/yyyyy/;/anotherPath/yyyyy/file2_name
```

Comment: I think OP would like the complete path. The input line `E;F;/anotherPath/yyyyy/zzz/file2_name` will give `E;F;/anotherPath/yyyyy/;/anotherPath/yyyyy/zzz/file2_name`, missing `zzz` in the third field.

Answer (score 2):

With sed:

```
sed 's|/.*/|&;&|' file
```

Output:

```
A;B;/Path/xx/;/Path/xx/file1_name
C;D;/anotherPath/yyyyy/;/anotherPath/yyyyy/file2_name
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying to do is extract the directory name and full file name as two separate components.

You can do this easily within awk using split() and arrays as -

cat /tmp/t.csv   | awk -F";" '{ n=split($3, a, "/"); s1=""; i=1; 
       while (i

A;B;//Path/xx;/Path/xx/file1_name
C;D;//anotherPath/yyyyy;/anotherPath/yyyyy/file2_name

Easier would be to use just bash and do 
cat /tmp/t.csv | sed -e 's/;/ /g' | while read a b c; do echo "$a;$b;`dirname $c`;$c" ; done

Comment: This is basically equivalent to Anubhava's answer, except this retains the [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html). Suggesting a shell loop seems misdirected.